# Stochastic integral and weak integral

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, banach-spaces, stochastic-calculus, bochner-spaces

Can the stochastic (Skorokhod) integral be seen as a special case of the weak of Pettis integral with the Banach space which win integrate into chosen appropriately?

Comment: I have a feeling that any questions involving Skorokhod integrals is much more suited to mathoverflow.com. Please take your question there, and offer more explanation.